# Reading different data types from file in Assets folder

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a file which I created with C++ which contains a mix of different data types (integers and floating point numbers).

I need to read the file and copy the data into variables.

I have tried using `ByteArrayOutputStream` but I'm getting odd results.

When I use the debugger and hover the cursor over my `ByteArrayOutputStream` object I can see the correct data being displayed (a mix of integers and floats).

But when I try to access that data using `ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray` the resulting array contains only integers.

Am I completely on the wrong track?

```
InputStream is;
//InputStream inputStream = openFileInput("test.txt");
AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
try {
        is = am.open("lake.ju");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error loading map.");
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }

System.out.println(is);
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

int i=0;
 for(int inc=0;inc<=100;++inc)
    {
     try {
        i = is.read();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     byteArrayOutputStream.write(i);
    }
    try {
        is.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: It's really unclear why you expect this to work, since you don't seem to be making any attempt to parse data types out of the stream, but rather are just moving bytes from one stream to another.  Also you should know that default binary storage formats are not formally portable between system; unless you specify the byte-level storage details, sometimes you will have a compatible generator and interpreter and other times you will not.

Comment: Ahh I see = thank you Chris. I have had better results with DataInputStream but I think you are 100% correct. The data does not seem to be replicable on Android

Comment: I think the above code is on the right track but I just cant extract the data from the buffer ( I have no idea how to do this). After I run this code in the debugger and hover the cursor over byteArrayOutputStream a window pops up. At the bottom I can see the correct mix of integers and floats. So it does seem that the data has been pulled from the file and loaded into the buffer. But I cant see how I can copy those individual elements into variables. Any help would be great.